# Build a test project

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

iam building a MAUI Project with a mstest project.
The MAUI project builds totally fine, the test project was building fine but i added a android and iOS as a targetedframeworks in the csproj file becasue i need to build the test for these platforms aswell. so i get the following error when iam trying to build the test project:

"Error Empty ResolveFrameworkReference.RuntimePackPath while trying to read runtime components manifest. ResolvedFrameworkReference available: { Microsoft.NETCore.App, RuntimePackPath:  } XXXapp.Test C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk\6.0.11\Sdk\RuntimeComponentManifest.targets"

could anybody please help, thanks

i tried to update the .net sdk but no success

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to run unit tests or device tests? In case of unit tests, you need a specific setup. I would also recommend using NUnit or xUnit instead of MSTest, unless you have a specific reason to use MSTest. Can you please also show what the **.csproj** files of both your MAUI App and your Test projects look like?